# Wine failed to insall msxml3 with winetricks

Tags: linux, debugging, visual-c++, msxml, wine

My wine version is 2.22 on Fedora 25.
I have also tested it on wine 3.0 RC-5 on Fedora 25 ,and it failed.

When I install msxml3 using winetricks it gave me errors like:

```
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
fixme:setupapi:SetupQueryInfOriginalFileInformationW (0x9b1640, 0, (nil), 0x8abe98): semi-stub
fixme:setupapi:SetupPromptReboot 0x145468, (nil), 1: stub
```

I think I have to  install msxml3 because it is required when installing vcrun2008 and vcrun 2010 in wine.

By the way,it also failed when I was installing vcrun2008 and vcrun2010.

Any idea?

Comment: Hello Jackson. Did you find any solution to that?